# how are smileys encoded in mysql utf-8 mb4 database?

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8, utf8mb4

I changed my mysql database to utf-8 mb4, so that users could enter smileys from their mobile phones / mac. It works (users can enter smileys and those smileys are shown in the web app on supported devices), but whenever I have a look at the table contents (via terminal or mysql workbench) it shows each smiley as a single question mark. How exactly are those smileys saved? I assume they got a utf-8 mb4 code, but is there any way to look at those?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect Workbench is running in utf8 mode, not utf8mb4.  Change that.

To further verify that the data is stored correctly, do a `SELECT HEX(col) ...` to see the actual bytes stored.  For example:   => F09F9881

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored/